# How to get overall category of business in JSON object after request in Yelp API

Tags: json, api, categories, yelp

In the category list in the documentation, there are overall categories (Food, Restaurants, Health), and many sub categories within them. However, when I make a request and parse the JSON, the only categories that are returned are the sub-categories.

Even the example json in the documentation doesn't have the overall categories
 "categories": [
        [
          "Local Flavor",
          "localflavor"
        ],
        [
          "Mass Media",
          "massmedia"
        ]
      ],

If I search for restaurants, the categories will return things like "italian, french, american", but not "restaurants". Is there a way to get the overall category in the json so I can use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [search API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api) instead, and set a `category_filter` according to [this list](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/category_list).
This should give you all the "objects" in the given category.

Something like this `http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?category_filter=restaurants`.

---

**Update**

It seems like I misunderstood a little... so you want to get the root category.
(eg. for "italian"–>"restaurants", "french"->restaurants, "car dealers"->automotive etc.)

I think you have two options:

1. Hardcode the dictionary of all restaurant subcategories (french,italian...) into a file (plist, json, whatever) and after getting the "object" you could check if the subcategory is included in the hard-coded subcategories dictionary.
2. Use the search API and provide the bussiness `id` and `category_filter` set to restaurants and check if it returns any result - if not, then the object is not in the right category.

The reason why I am suggesting to hard code it is, because Yelp doesn't provide an API to get complete list of categories.

In my opinion I would try the approach #1, because it is less intensive on the network side and a dictionary is blazing fast.

But to answer your initial question, no it is not possible to have the root category in the JSON file.

Comment: Actually, I'm not trying to filter a search from  a category. I am trying to retrieve whether or not a business falls into the restaurant category, after I send the request. This is so I can run something like `if(category == restaurants){//do stuff}

Comment: If root category is like "food" or "restaurants" then yes I need the root category

Comment: Yes, I've added an update that explains how you can achieve it :)

Comment: thanks... again. I guess thats what i came to after looking around extensively too. theres like what... 500 categories? lol

Comment: It is not that bad, there is exactly 117 restaurant categories and 35 food categories. 152 entries in a dictionary is nothing. Dictionaries are really fast thanks to hash tables, so you don't have to worry about speed.

Comment: For the purposes of my app, I need to categorize all of them (or most of them). thanks for your help.

Comment: I have a similar need. I would like to return whether the businesses I have in my list are restaurant, hair salon, car rental, etc. I know that about 95% of my 700 records are restaurants but it'd be so much easier if I can just confirm that by passing the business id into Yelp API. Any chance this is available now?